# I have this HTML. How to make each of the section next to one another?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="sections-div">
    <section class="eachsec">section1</section>
    <section class="eachsec">section2</section>
    <section class="eachsec">section3</section>
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.sections-div {
    display: inline;
}
```

[image: It is visible like this now.]

I want it to appear in the format

```
"section1                    section2                     section3"
```

How to solve it using block or inline or inline-block?

TIA

Comment: You are applying your style to the container, not the child sections. There are literally hundreds of questions covering this if you search this site for anything like: "Show elements next to each other".

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following CSS for the child tags using `inline-block` or `inline`:

```css
.eachsec {
  display: inline-block;
}

/*.eachsec {
  display: inline;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="sections-div">
  <section class="eachsec">section1</section>
  <section class="eachsec">section2</section>
  <section class="eachsec">section3</section>
</div>
```

> `inline`: Displays an element as an inline element. Any height and width properties will have no effect.
> `inline-block`: Displays an element as an inline-level block container. You CAN set height and width values.

NOTE: Section tag grouped the generic block of related contents. You should avoid using the `<section>` tag to inline any content.

Answer (score -1):

hello you an use the display : flex; together with flex-direction : row; .We can also use the grid system layout

```css
.sections-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:space-between; /* try also justify-content: space-around; */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="sections-div">
    <section class="eachsec">section1</section>
    <section class="eachsec">section2</section>
    <section class="eachsec">section3</section>
</div>
```